# ionic iframe not displaying youtube/vimeo links on iOS, ok in browser and Android

Tags: ios, video, iframe, ionic-framework, youtube

On an emulator on my MacBook and on an Android real phone it works ok.
But not on a real iOS (version 10/ iPhone6Plus, version 9.3.5 / )

I've tried:

```
<div class="video-container">
                <iframe ng-src="{{trustSrc('https://www.youtube.com/embed/wyVM1evRxNw')}}" frameborder="0" width="560" height="315"></iframe>

            </div>
            <div class="video-container">
                <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/wyVM1evRxNw" frameborder="0" width="560" height="315"></iframe>

            </div>
            <div class="video-container">
                 <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/183295075" frameborder="0" width="560" height="315"></iframe>
            </div>
```

in config.xml I've added:

```
 <access origin="*"/>
```

Comment: Hi, have u solved the issue? can u help me?